# What is the ECMAScript feature that allows developers to put spacing between numbers?

Tags: javascript, numbers, ecmascript-next

I vaguely remember newer versions of JS/ECMAScript allow users to put spaces within numbers for readability. E.g. something like:

```
const age = 1 000 000;
```

However my linter complains, probably because it needs to allow the rule - what's the name of this ECMAScript feature?

Sadly searches for 'numeric separators JavaScript' have only found answers about formatting numbers for display to users.

Comment: You mean underscore as a [numeric separator](https://www.google.com/search?q=numeric+separators+javascript&ei=BioSYcSnArSD8gKV3IGwCg&oq=numeric+separa&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgAEEM6BQgAEJECOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoICC4QsQMQgwE6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEEM6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsILhCABBDHARCvAToICAAQgAQQyQNKBAhBGABQ_S5Y8kpg8lJoA3ACeACAAbEEiAHjMpIBBzMtNC45LjKYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&safe=active&ssui=on): `1_000_000`?

Comment: @Yousaf I do! Thanks.

Comment: @Yousaf if you add that as an answer I’ll mark it as accepted since you were first.

Comment: You can accept the answer provided below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **underscores** as separators to make large numbers more readable.
This is a part of ES2021 (https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-NumericLiteralSeparator).